# How does Python set the installation directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I embedded Python 3.7 into my C++ application and ship my own Python installation. Here is my application directory (for Windows and macOS):

```
- foo.exe
- foo.app/
- python37/
   |- bin/    <-- for macOS
   |  |- python
   |
   |- Lib/
   |  |...
   |  |- site-packages/
   |
   |- python.exe
```

Executing the following commands on Windows installs the modules correctly in the site-packages directory.

```
$ python.exe get-pip.py
$ pip3 install xyz
```

However, on macOS the following command...

```
$ export PYTHONHOME=/path/to/foo/python37
$ bin/python get-pip.py
```

...installs `pip` in `./python37/Lib/python37/site-packages`. Which means the subfolder in `Lib/python37` is incorrect. Does anyone know why this happens? PYTHONHOME seems to be correctly set (simply the first `./python37`) and I don't have an explanation for that behaviour.

Comment: We need more details. Where is the python executable? Where are installed the modules? Where do you expect them to be installed?

Comment: Understood, I will update my question in a few minutes.

Comment: @DanielStephens, are you saying that in windows you rather see pip being installed at `/path/to/python3.7/Lib/site-packages/pip`, however in macOs it is at  `/path/to/python37/Lib/python37/site-packages/pip` with an extra sub directory `Lib/python37`?

Comment: Correct! And I don't know where that additional python37 comes from between `Lib/` and `site-packages`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is heavily based upon the installation references provided by the python3 guide.
[install guide](https://docs.python.org/3/install/)

Python modules can be built from scratch using build and install commands: (Also, can be done in one run with `python setup.py install`)

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Now, I would not concentrate towards build, but more on the install. The install command typically copies all the `build/lib` files into a choosen directory and if no directory is choosen then default is chosen. The location varies from platform to platform, also there are variants in them as well like Unix (Pure) and Unix (Non Pure). Now, let us look at the following below:

```
Unix (pure)1: /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages   
Unix (non-pure): /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages 
Windows: C:\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages
```

Now, it can be seen that by default for Unix platforms the `/lib/pythonX.Y` is added by default. This behavior can also be modified specifying options during `python setup.py install` (More on [install guide](https://docs.python.org/3/install/) about it) I have not tried them myself.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can set these options permanently for my environment/application?

Comment: I have not tried it out myself, but reading the doc I can see that Alternative and Custom installations seem to setup everything permanently with a proper build and install.

Comment: @DanielStephens if you feel this answer was useful you could accept it as an answer.